# What is a way of re-selecting a random set of check boxes again using Selenium Python?

Tags: python-3.x, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is there are several check boxes with the name tag starting with "CHK_(number here)". What I want to do is select 5 random check boxes, click them (to have them checked), once they are checked, click a sort button which is defined as "sort_selected_button", and finally un-select the random checked boxes. The final step is where I am having trouble with.

This is being done on Internet Explorer 11. This is my first time getting into Selenium Python for IE 11 so I would appreciate any help.

```
# Checks several batches, sort them with the Sort button, and then deselect
def check_sort_deselect_batches_selected(self):
    select_random_batches = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@name, 'CHK_')]")

    for x in range(5):
        option = random.choice(select_random_batches)
        option.click()
        return option
    else:
        self.driver.find_element(*LeftSidebarLocators.sort_selected_button).click()

    time.sleep(2)
```

I have been able to be rid of any error messages; however, the only issue is on how to select the 5 randomly selected check boxes again after they have been sorted.  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you please explain your scenario more? It sounds like you are picking 5 random numbers and then clicking the corresponding options. After that, you sort the options and then want to select them again? This is where I got lost. An example would really help here. Make something up if the selections are private, etc. Show us List 1 (unsorted), how you want to check 5 boxes, sort, and then List 1 (sorted differently?) and choose them again... or whatever the scenario is.

Comment: You should edit your question and put the updated scenario with more details there. In general you want to put all the relevant info that would be needed to help people understand your question and potentially answer it in the question itself so everyone doesn't have to read all the comments to get all the important bits.

Comment: Went ahead and updated my scenario so it can be clearer for everyone seeing the post. I went ahead and updated the coding @JeffC: was wondering if there would be a difference between 'is_checked()' to 'is_selected()'? I changed the coding to 'is_selected' instead and I am getting an error message saying "Message: Element is no longer valid." The scenario runs but stops at the point I had trouble with: deselecting the check boxes after they have been sorted. (Also, thanks for the help Jeff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method `is_checked()` that will return `True` if the box is checked. You can use this to determine which of the boxes are checked and then click them again to uncheck each. Before we get to the final code, I would make a couple suggestions:

1. One issue you might run into with your current code is that you randomly pick the same number twice in your `for` loop. If that happens, you will uncheck the box that you already checked leaving you with only 4 checked items.

   To fix this, you can use a `filter` to grab only the checked boxes and repeat the loop until you get a `len()` of 5. If you get the same random number again, the click is skipped and you loop again.
2. The `else` statement will always get executed since you have no `break` in your `for` loop so it can be safely removed. See [the docs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause) for more info.

For the new code, you can use another `filter` to grab only the checked boxes and then loop through them, clicking each one to uncheck all the checkboxes.

```
# Checks several batches, sort them with the Sort button, and then deselect
def check_sort_deselect_batches_selected(self):
    select_random_batches = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@name, 'CHK_')]")

    # loop until the count of checked elements is 5
    while len(list(filter(lambda e: e.is_checked(), select_random_batches))) < 5
        option = random.choice(select_random_batches)
        # make sure that the random choice isn't already checked
        if not option.is_selected()
            option.click()

    self.driver.find_element(*LeftSidebarLocators.sort_selected_button).click()

    # refetch the checkboxes after the sorting
    select_random_batches = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@name, 'CHK_')]")

    # loop through the list of checked elements and deselect each
    for e in list(filter(lambda e: e.is_checked(), select_random_batches))
        e.click()

    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: I'm going to put my comment down here in response to your comment under your question since it was referring to my answer. There is no `is_checked()` in python, only `is_selected()` (see [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)). Also, I edited my code to add a line to refetch the checkboxes after the sort. I'm assuming the sort refreshes the page or otherwise updates a part of the page that was causing that error. Try now.

Comment: It worked Jeff, thank you so much. I did not know you would have to refetch the element even it has already been called from the beginning.

Comment: Well it depends on the situation. If you aren't refreshing the page (or part of the page), then you wouldn't need to refetch. If you DO refresh the page and you reference a variable like this, you will likely get stale element exceptions.